# Java GUI KeyEvent and stuff

Tags: java, user-interface

Ok.... what I want is for the user to choose what input he wants for my keyPress with a GUI, which i have a place i save and load a config with the VK Key code.
So VK_W = 87 and it saves 87 in a config file.  So i want to have a Choice or button that can pick what VK/number that will be pick to be KeyPressed.

Here is my code

```
public class Twitchbot extends PircBot {
int VK_W = 87;
int VK_S = 83;

int[] saveInformation = {VK_W, VK_S};

int VK_WLoc = 0;
int VK_SLoc = 1;



public Twitchbot() {
    configRead("Config.cfg");
    updateConfig();
    configSave("Config.cfg");


    this.setName("Rex__Bot");
}

private void updateConfig(){
    System.out.println(VK_W);
    System.out.println(VK_S);

    VK_W = saveInformation[VK_WLoc];
    VK_S = saveInformation[VK_SLoc];

    System.out.println(VK_W);
    System.out.println(VK_S);
}

private void configRead(String filePath) {
    File inputFile;
    BufferedReader inputReader;

    try {
        inputFile = new File(filePath);
        inputReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));

        for(int i = 0; i < saveInformation.length; i++){
            saveInformation[i] = Integer.parseInt(inputReader.readLine());
        }

        System.out.println(filePath);
        inputReader.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void configSave(String filePath) {
    File outputFile;
    BufferedWriter outputWriter;

    try {
        outputFile = new File(filePath);
        outputWriter = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outputFile));


        for(int i = 0; i < saveInformation.length; i++){
            outputWriter.write(Integer.toString(saveInformation[i]) + "\n");
        }

        outputWriter.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}



public void onMessage(String channel, String sender, String login, String hostname, String message) {



    if(message.equals("up")) {
        try {
            Robot r = new Robot();
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
            r.delay(300);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_W);

        }catch(Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

}
```

Comment: So... what is the question?

Comment: How can i make that happen? What i said uptop.

Comment: Java OR Swift...and didn't we do this?

Comment: did we? and java... for right now i just want to be able to edit inside of the config file and it change what key is going to be keypressed

Comment: @nyanchan you have to understand, StackOverflow isn't for 'building it for you'. You've already expressed the you want to make a GUI in Java, so the standard libraries in Java to do so are **Swing** (which is outdated but still widely used) or **JavaFX** (the new kid on the block). I would suggest reading some [Java GUI Tutorials](http://cs.nyu.edu/~yap/classes/visual/03s/lect/l7/) to start before working on this.

Comment: alright i understand, sorry for bothering you.